# In JSF 2.2, how to launch a method from a shared menu, wiithout leaving the current page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

The title says almost all. Just an important precision: the menu is in a template and so is shared by several pages and I don't know the page from which the user will choose the menu item.

I tried with a h:commandLink but I have a problem with the redirection to the same page. Perhaps there is a another kind of solution?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and add the relevant code? What do you mean by 'launch a method' and 'shared menu'?

Comment: Probably you need to use an ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it an asynchronous submit instead of a synchronous submit. Nest in a `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandLink>
```

If you intend to execute or render some specific parts, specify them accordingly in the `execute` and/or `render` attribute of `<f:ajax>`. They both defaults to `@this` and `@none` respectively. E.g.

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```